# Does GoogleAccountCredential provide refresh token?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, credentials, google-drive-api

I am planning to write an Android App to fetch files from Google Drive.

If the storage is huge, definitely it will take hours to download the files. In such case, I would need refresh token to complete the process. As far as I know, `GoogleAccountCredential` doesn't provide any methods to get the refresh token.

I want to send the token and refresh token to a websevice so that it will download the files on behalf of my app and store it in the server.

Is there any way to get refresh tokens from `GoogleAccountCredential`?

Comment: do you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about android but in java if you want to get refresh token, you must request GoogleAuthorizationaflow for offline access type..

like
flow =new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
              .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();

Comment: Thanks for the reply user2032988.
But I want to use GoogleAccountCredential to retrieve token as it functions as a wrapper to GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and I will get token in two steps and I really dont want to parse the Authcode returned first and then exchange it for access toke.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.
You need to ask for a server-side scope to get the refresh-token:

```
String MY_SCOPE = ""; // put your score here, e.g. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
String CLIENT_ID = "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com";
String SERVER_SCOPE = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:" + MY_SCOPE;

GoogleAccountCredential cred = new GoogleAccountCredential(context, SERVER_SCOPE).setSelectedAccountName("hello@gmail.com");
cred.getToken();
```